# Can i use tags templates in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

For example:

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    {{ include("../tags/inputBox",{name:'abcd',value:1234}); }}
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    {{ include("../tags/inputBox",{name:'efg',value:567}); }}
</div>
```

Or it is not provided?

Comment: is it something like `ng-include` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates that you want to be processed by Angular (binding, creating components, directives, ...) have to be provided statically. There are some ugly workarounds without any guarantee be work in the future.

The only officially supported way is as far as I know  [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about injecting dynamic template with values, parse it, show it and all  with `ng-include`(`#Angular1`) kinda directive then **[look at here github issue`(fyi #Angular2)`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2753)**, it is clearly stated that

> **`ng-include` will not be added as it has security issues**

But you can surely use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html).